Checkerboard origin shifts during camera calibration
I am using the Matlab Calibration App to calibrate my camera, and I’ve noticed the placement of the checkerboard origin changes for different calibrated images.
A standard checkerboard has four corners, assume A, B, C and D. The checkerboard origin isn’t fixed to one corner across all the images in my case. For example, in some calibration images, the origin is placed near corner A, while in others it is placed near corner B.
Should the checkerboard origin remain fixed at a specific corner (e.g., corner A) throughout all calibration images? If so, is there a way to enforce this in the Matlab Calibration App? I couldn't find an option to manually set or fix the checkerboard origin, and I’m unsure if this variation impacts the calibration results.

Already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37577579/1435240

@FrancescoCallari That seems not answer my question. My checkerboard is 9 columns * 9 rows with each grid element 35mm and a white border the same size as one grid element. When capturing images, I can ensure all grid elements are visible, but sometimes the white border may be not fully visible. When capturing images, the camera is fixed and I only moves checkerboard. Is it ok to roll the checkerboard 180 degree or 270 degree?

A board with an odd number of rows is invariant (looks the same) under rotations by multiples of 90deg. If even, invariant under 180deg rotations. If board is entirely visible, for the boundary to shift you must miss most corners of an edge - check focus. Having a uniform boundary the same color as the board squares is a bad idea, because the corners at the edges are not saddle points. Cut at the boundary or use a neutral gray.

@FrancescoCallari The boarder in Capture Images section in Prepare Camera and Capture Images For Camera Calibration - MathWorks is also white, my checkerboard is the same color with it. I take two images 1 and 2 of my calibration result. The checkerboard origins are both on bottom left. However, the origins are at different corner, I identify this by a specification sentence C400-9×9-35 circled red in images.

Re-read what I wrote about regular checkerboard with an odd number of rows. Then look again carefully at your images 1 and 2 and ask yourself: how can the algorithm tell that you have rotated the board by 90deg, if it only knows how to detect and sort corners? That scribble you highlighted in a read bubble? It does not even know it exists.

@FrancescoCallari Thanks, understood. It seems there isn't a way to manually point out the origin for the algorithm. I check my calibration images again and find that there exists 3, 4 origin shifts even when I didn't rotate the checkerboard much. In this situation, should I remove the images that origin is in the wrong corner? I don't quite understand what does check focus mean in "If board is entirely visible, for the boundary to shift you must miss most corners of an edge - check focus.", my camera is fixed focus.

Added a response to the question. Please upvote/accept if you find it useful.

Recommendations:

Do not use a square checkerboard with an odd number of rows, since it is not invariant under rotation.
Remove the border.
Use a better algorithm and checkerboard pattern. See, for example, notes here.

